# Make constrained functions a typeclass instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I'm relatively new to Haskell so I apologise if I'm not getting the terminology completely correct.

I'm trying to write an implementation of [Linear Temporal Logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_temporal_logic) using Haskell where an expression can be constructed and then applied to a list of elements to produce a Boolean result using a function with the following signature:

```hs
evaluate :: Expression a -> [a] -> Bool
```

With `Expression a` being an algebraic data type defined something like this:

```hs
data Expression a = Conjunction (Expression a) (Expression a)
                  | Disjunction (Expression a) (Expression a)
                  | Next (Expression a)
                  | Always (Expression a)
                  | Eventually (Expression a)
                  | Until (Expression a) (Expression a)
                  | Predicate (a -> Bool)
                  -- etc. etc.
```

This all works fine, but I'd like to make constructing expressions a little more elegant by defining smart constructors, ideally that could be used something a little like this:

```hs
numExpr :: Num a => Expression a
numExpr = eventually (== 10) `or` eventually (== 5)
```

So far my attempts at achieving this have involved something like the following:

```hs
eventually :: Expressable e => e a -> Expression a
eventually = Eventually . expresss

or :: (Expressable e, Expressable f) => e a -> f a -> Expression a
or x y = Or (express x) (express y)

-- and so on

class Expressable e where
  express :: e a -> Expression a

instance Expressable Expression where
  express = id

-- This is what I'd like to do:

type Pred a = a -> Bool

instance Expressable Pred where
  express = Predicate
```

However the latter doesn't work. I've tried using various GHC extensions (LiberalTypeSynonyms, TypeSynonymInstances) but nothing has seemed to work. Is this kind of thing possible or even a good idea? Is there a good reason why the type system will not allow this kind of thing? Is there a better way to structure this that would work?

I know I could use a short function name with a signature like `p :: (a -> Bool) -> Expression a` but this still feels a little inelegant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your approach you need to link the `a` which is the argument of `Pred` to the `a` in the signature of `express`. These have to be the same, but you can't require that in your class / instances.

You can however try something like this, with a bunch of extensions on:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances #-}

data Expression a = Conjunction (Expression a) (Expression a)
                  | Disjunction (Expression a) (Expression a)
                  | Next (Expression a)
                  | Always (Expression a)
                  | Eventually (Expression a)
                  | Until (Expression a) (Expression a)
                  | Predicate (a -> Bool)

class Expressable e a where
      express :: e -> Expression a
    
instance Expressable (Expression a) a where
  express = id

type Pred a = a -> Bool

instance Expressable (Pred a) a where
  express = Predicate

eventually :: Expressable e a => e -> Expression a
eventually = Eventually . express

or :: (Expressable e a, Expressable f a) => e -> f -> Expression a
or x y = Disjunction (express x) (express y)
```

I'm not terribly convinced it is a good idea to use such machinery only to avoid writing `Predicate` on the atomic formulae, but you might give it a whirl and see if it works well enough in practice.

Answer (score 2):

A `newtype` instead of `type` would work:

```
newtype Pred a = Pred (a -> Bool)

instance Expressable Pred where
  express (Pred p) = Predicate p
```

In your case, `Pred` in `instance Expressable Pred where` is a partially applied type synonym and those are basically never allowed (see [`LiberalTypeSynonyms`](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#liberalised-type-synonyms) for the exception).

Comment: Thanks Alexey, I am aware that I could use a newtype but that would complicate the syntax for the smart constructors as I'd have to prepend any functions with `Pred` or a function with a `(a -> Bool) -> Pred a signature, which is what I was trying to avoid.